# Differnece between these tags in a wsdl file <wsdl:types> and <types>

Tags: java, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am trying to understand the flow of an application. I have two wsdl files,

In one of the WSDL it has the following representation

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema>
         <xsd:import>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message>
         <wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
```

In another WSDL file this is the following specification.

```
<types>
        <xsd:schema >
            <xsd:import>
                     <xsd:element >
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
</types>

<message name="">
        <part />
</message>
```

I would like to know what is the difference between these two.

Thanks

Venkat.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, in the second WSDL the default namespace is the same as alias `wsdl` in the first.  To confirm, post all namespace references in both files.